How to delete a netplan configuration from network sytem setting on Ubuntu?
I created a network configuration file under the folder of /etc/netplan, and then run sudo netplan apply to activate it.
I'm afraid that the setting may conflict with the network setting in the network setting dialog. My question is that how can I remove the above setting from network setting dialog? Because
